# How Global variable Works in javascript within Function in two javascript file

Tags: javascript, global-variables

first javascript file :

```
var x = 6;
```

second javascript file :

```
alert(x); answer = 6;
```

Problem:

first java script file

```
var x ;

function demo{
    window.x = 6 ; or x =6;`}
```

second java script file :

```
alert(x)
```

answer is getting undefined?

Comment: You must call `demo()` to actually declare the variable before accessing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problems:

1. Functions are not declared in a way you've done.
2. Even if you'd done that correctly, you need to call it, for it to have effect.

### Solution:

```
function demo(){
 window.x = 6; //or x =6;
}; demo(); // call it
```

Comment: if u means in second.js if i called demo() i will get x = 6 value

Comment: @PrashantSable glad to have helped. Do mark it as answer if it helped :)

Comment: Amit Joki what about if function takes to much time to processed? My function takes too much time to processed so i did that on first page of html. Now I am on second page of html and i need that data, to get that data i needs to called again function and that is actually useless.

Comment: @PrashantSable javascript is very fast and doesn't take even a second for your function and since everything is synchronous here, it will not be a problem. BTW, you can accept my answer by clicking on the tick ;)

Comment: actually i am dealing with phonegap api and i fetch certain data from that and store into array, is there any way to fetch that array in another html page? Since data get flush after closing first page